# The Walmart clerk takes pictures of my IMEI # and Phone numbers

Tags: mobile

I went to WalMart looking for a cover for my new LG-Stylo Smartphone. I asked a one of the workers where to find them and he said they don't have any. Come to find out he has the same phone so I start asking questions.Then it gets weird.I tell him I'm not happy with the camera. Next thing you know the phones in his hand, he goes to my Settings/About phone/Status then takes a picture of my phone number, IMEI# and IMEI SV#. He tried to take pictures other setting info when I asked "Should I really be letting you do that"? When he gave me some line about, he just wants to get info on the camera etc...I've been uneasy about the whole event ever since. For Crying out loud I just surrendered my Antique Flip Phone for the Smartphone. This this phone has far more personal and vital info then my flip phone did. It just happened so quick. What should I do?

Comment: Call WalMart and ask about this practice before you go crazy. If it turns out that this is not normal you can help identify the individual.

Comment: At the place I used to work before, our standard practice was to take the IMEIs of all phones we sold. I can't see why you would do that just to sell a case or an accessory though.

Answer (score 3):

Get a new phone, seriously. If someone has your IMEI they can authenticate with your IMEI to whatever cellular provider (this is not easy, but provenly possible with the required skills). If your IMEI is used for any kind of illegal operation and police start investigating, this can get you into deep trouble. E.g. someone threatens to blow a bomb using your IMEI. It is very likely that police discover the fraud in such a case but i'd not want to get into something like this.